# Firefox addon localization

Tags: localization, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have problem with localization my addon. I followed [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/l10n.html) tutorial on `Using Localized Strings in Preferences` but I can't compile my addon because I use polish characters `ć` and others.

I've made `locale` folder and put there `pl-PL.properties` file with this content:

```
my_tag_title = Co robić?
```

and I got error:

```
Following locale file is not a valid UTF-8 file: C:\path\pl-PL.properties
'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 22: invalid continuation byte"
```

Is there way to put special characters directly inside package.json?

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure you saved the file in UTF-8?

Comment: No, I had to convert file from ANSI to UTF-8 without BOM and it started working. Post your comment as answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that the locale file is saved in UTF-8 format.

Comment: Additionally I don't have to make locale file, I can put special characters to `package.json` file, but it need to be coded in UTF-8.